# Instant Java time no muestra la fecha

Tags: java, spring, rest

hola tengo un servicio de login que deberia retornar la fecha de expiracion de token, el momento de la fecha lo tomo con un Instant de java time pero la respuesta del postman no la obtengo, sino que me muestra los milisegundos o nanosegundos la verdad no se, pero es extraño porque al debuguear y imprimir un log esta todo bien pero la respuesta del controller al postman esta mal.

Este es mi metodo del controller:

```
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public AuthenticationResponse login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        return authService.login(loginRequest);
    }
```

Este es mi authservice:

```
    public AuthenticationResponse login(LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(),
                loginRequest.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);
        String token = jwtProvider.generateToken(authenticate);
        Instant resp = Instant.now().plusMillis(jwtProvider.getJwtExpirationInMillis());
        System.out.println(resp);

        return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                .authenticationToken(token)
                .refreshToken(refreshTokenService.generateRefreshToken().getToken())
                .expiresAt(resp)
                .username(loginRequest.getUsername())
                .build();
    }
```

Alli testeando probe el system.out.print todo parece bien incluso debugeando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede ver que expiresAt se le dio el valor correcto del momento de la fecha, pero la respuesta de mi controller al postman es esta :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

expiresAt me da ese formato :(

mi dto de respuesta es este:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.time.Instant;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class AuthenticationResponse {
    private String authenticationToken;
    private String refreshToken;
    private Instant expiresAt;
    private String username;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/time/Instant.html la clase `Instant` almacena un `long` que representa `epoch-seconds` y un `int` que representa `nanosecond-of-second` por lo tanto no una representa una fecha, hay que tener en cuenta que las las fechas como DateTime y LocalDateTime no son serializables para pasar por REST, en un caso similar lo solucione definiendo un formato de fecha estandar tanto en el servidor como en el cliente de forma que la fecha la convertia a String para dar respuesta en el servicio y en el cliente la transformaba de nuevo a LocalDateTime de acuerdo al formato definido.